# Solving the equation $\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{4x+1} = 5$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> Find the set of all the solutions of the equation
> $$\sqrt{x+2} + \sqrt{4x+1} = 5$$

I got two solutions using the quadratic formula: $238/9$ and $2$, but only $2$ works in the original equation, so the other solution is extraneous.

> Are these the solutions if you use the quadratic formula, and is there a way of solving the equation without squaring the radicals?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $x=238/9$ solves $-\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{4x+1}=5$

Comment: Please don't use abbreviations like qf. (quite fascinating, quadrilateral formula, quick factor ?)   Please take the time to write out what you mean.

Comment: You should show a few steps how you got to the equation you submitted to the quadratic formula.  It is much easier to answer when we see the quadratic you got.  Please do not ask people to duplicate your work.

Answer (score 1):

Without taking squares. By inspection, $2$ is a solution. Notice that both square roots are increasing functions so the LHS is an increasing function for $x\ge -1/4$. For smaller $x$ the LHS is not defined. Thus the equation can have only one solution, $x=2$ (an increasing function takes any value at most once).

Answer (score -1):

Hint

Let $\sqrt{x+2}=a\ge0$

and $\sqrt{4x+1}=b\ge0$

Now $a+b=5$

and $b^2-4a^2=4x+1-4(x+2)$

$(5-a)^2-4a^2=-7$

Can you take it from here?